# How to get number of lines of text in TMP_Inputfield

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I make some Letter program by using Unity.

For Text Input, I use TMP_Inputfield, and I need to get the line of text, because I want to make this programs respond well when I press the Enter key.

When I set the line Limit as 5, and Line Type as Multi Line NewLine, If I enter the fifth line and press the enter key, the cursor moves to the next line.

In this case, I want to deactivate TMP_Inputfield or activate next TMP_Inputfield.

In the TMP_Inputfield, Only the Line_limit could be set up, but cannot get the lines of text.

In order to deal with such cases, I want to get the lines of text. how can I get this?

[image: Here is my TMP_Inputfield settings.]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what exactly you are asking.

You get/set this via [`lineLimit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/api/TMPro.TMP_InputField.html#TMPro_TMP_InputField_lineLimit) .. and for getting the amount of lines in a string you could probably do

```
using System.Linq;

...

var lineCount = inputField.text.Count(c => c == '\n') + 1;
```

or without Linq

```
var lineCount = inputField.text.Split('\n').Length;
```

Comment: derHugo, Thanks.
But if text Length is too long, text would be go to next line automatically without '\n'.

In this case, how do we check the number of lines?